# Step-by-step process to find $3f(x)+f(g(x))$ and $4f(g(x))+2f(-3)$ when $f(x)=e^{x^2}-1$ and $g(x) = \sqrt{x^2-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can't understand my teacher explanation about how to solve this kind of operations with functions (I'm sorry for my english)

He gave us these functions

$$f(x)=e^{x^2}-1 \qquad g(x) = \sqrt{x^2-1}$$

And I need to find those values in these other functions

a) $\quad 3f(x)+f(g(x))$

b) $\quad 4f(g(x))+2f(-3)$

I will not lie, I have no idea how to solve this, I know i need to find the first functions inside the others but not idea how or what steps to follow, can you explain it to me please? I'm begging you, thanks.

Answer to A)

$\quad 3f(x)+f(g(x))$

$\quad 3f(e^{x^2}-1)+f(\sqrt{x^2-1} )$

$\quad 3(e^{x^2}-1)+(e^{x^2}-1) $

$\quad 3e^{x^2}-3+e^{x^2}-1$

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin it's a library? I don't get it

Comment: It’s the way to typeset mathematics in this site so they are properly formatted and easy to read. [Here’s a tutorial, found in the FAQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Another user was kind enough to fix your post so it is legible.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not really "solve" anything here.

If the value of $x$ is given, you can compute the value of $f(x), g(x)$ etc., right?

Once you know the values of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, you can easily compute the other expressions involving $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

Let $f(x) = e^{x^2} - 1$ and $g(x) = \sqrt{x^2 - 1}$

For example, if you are to calculate $f(1)$, you need to replace $x$ by $1$ in the expression for $f(x)$

$f(1) = e^{1^2} - 1 = e - 1$ and $g(1) = \sqrt{1^2 - 1} = 0$

Similarly, you replace $x$ by $g(x)$ in the expression for $f(x)$ when you need to evaluate $f(g(x))$

$f(g(x)) = e^{{g(x)}^2} - 1 = e^{x^2 - 1} - 1$

$3f(x) + f(g(x)) = 3(e^{x^2} - 1) + e^{x^2 - 1} - 1$

Comment: The 3 and 4 before f is multiplying, right?

Comment: Yes, let me illustrate...

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation, it was really helpul, can you tell me what do you think of my answer to letter A? please I put it below the question

Comment: I edited my answer. Please compare now.

Comment: Thank you, I will do the exercise again and see why mine is different to your answer but very close

Answer (score 1):

Let $f,g:I \to \mathbb{R}$, when $I\subset \mathbb{R}$we define

$(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$

$(f \cdot g)(x)=f(x)g(x)$

$(f \circ g)(x)=f(g(x))$ it is first apply $g$ and then $f$ it iff $g(x)\in \text{Dom $f$}$

In your case $f(x)=e^{x^2}-1$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{x^2-1}$ I will help you with $b)$

$$4f(g(x))+2f(-3)=4f(\sqrt{x^2-1})+2(e^{9}-1)$$
$$ =4(e^{x^2-1}-1)+2(e^{9}-1)$$
$$ =4e^{x^2-1}-4+2e^{9}-2$$
$$ \fbox {$ 4e^{x^2-1}+2e^{9}-6 $}$$
You should be able to do the $a)$
**Hint**
Notice that $f(a)$ is the value of put the number $a$ in the formula given by $f$

$$3f(x)+f(g(x))=3(e^{x^2}-1)+e^{x^2-1}-1$$
$$=3e^{x^2}-3+e^{x^2-1}-1$$
$$\fbox { $3e^{x^2}+e^{x^2-1}-4$ }$$

Comment: Thank you so much, yes i will try to make the a, but it is `2e9−1` I mean 9 - 1 or it would be just e9 - 1 because the 1 is not in the same level as the 9

Comment: Yes, you are right, I make a error

Comment: Why -3 is affecting the x^2 and not -1?

Comment: If you have $f(x)=x^2-1$ and you want calculate $f(a)$ for $a$ a real number, you need substitute the value of $a$ only in the places when you see $x$, it is $f(a)=a^2-1$ and $a$ don´t affect $-1$.In our case  $f(x)=e^{x^2}-1$ and $f(-3)=e^{(-3)^2}-1=e^{9}-1$ and $-3$ don´t afect $-1$ due to $-1$ don´t depend of the value of $x$

Comment: I get it thank you so much i will try with this information

Comment: I´m glad of can help you, I´m sure that you can compute $a)$

Comment: Can I put my answer in the question to the A and tell me if it is okay please?

Comment: Yes I can help to do it

Comment: Can you check it please? I edited the question and I put the answer below

Comment: You are right, good work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119652/discussion-between-nabla-and-professor-zoom).

Comment: I sent you a message in the chat, can you check it? or tell me why you say i'm right? you said I was wrong and I need to know this